# Google Cloud Dataflow read from Elasticsearch error

Tags: elasticsearch, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have an Apache Beam pipeline reading from an AWS Elasticsearch cluster. The pipeline code is as follows:

```
       PCollection<String> output =
            pipeline.apply(
                    ElasticsearchIO.read().withConnectionConfiguration(
                            ElasticsearchIO.ConnectionConfiguration.create(
                                    hostName,
                                    options.getElasticSearchIndex(),
                                    options.getElasticSearchType()
                                    )
                    )
            );
         output.apply(TextIO.write().to("gs://<bucket-name>/test.txt")
                .withSuffix(".txt"));

        pipeline.run();
```

The job is deployed without any errors. I set the maxNumWorkers to 3 just to test my code initially. But the pipeline stalls and does not process any of the data.

When I look at the Google Cloud Logs, I see the following log entries:

```
Proposing dynamic split of work unit <project>;<hash> at {"fractionConsumed":0.5}

Rejecting split request because custom reader returned null residual source.
```

I see these logs getting generated over and over again. I let the pipeline run for 20-30 mins but there seems to be no progress.

I'm not sure how to debug this issue. Any thoughts on how to proceed?

EDIT: Updated pipeline code.

Comment: Are you able to run the code locally with the DirectRunner? What version of the SDK are you using?

Comment: I was/am not able to run the code locally with the DirectRunner. This error turned out to be harmless and the pipeline functioned as expected. BTW, I was on 2.23.0 Beam Java SDK.